# Prove that a language is not context free

Tags: computability, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I was solving some hard exercises on context free grammer.

Consider the language
L={w∈{a,b}^{*} :the length of the longest substring of all b’s in w is longer than any of the length of substring of just a’s in w}.

Prove that L is not context free.

I have tried this problem using pumping lemma and closure properties. How to go about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Got it. Used pumping lemma on a^mb^{m+1}c^m.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the pumping length. Then $b^pa^{p+1}\in L$ and also $b^{r}a^{p+1}$ for many $r>p$, contradiction.

Comment: Isn't this proof for just regular languages? I am trying to use pumping lemma for context free.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the pumping length. 
Then $а^{p}b^{p+1}a^{p}\in L$. $w = xyzuv. |yu|>=1 |yzu|<= p$.

If yzu is only of 1 letter it's easy to see that $xy^{0}zu^{0}v$ it's not in L.

If yzu  consist of 2 letters , 
then $xy^{0}zu^{0}v = а^{p-r}b^{p+1-t}a^{p}$  or $ а^{p}b^{p+1-t}a^{p-r}$ and since $p>=p+1-t$ the string obviously are not in L